# Stop Safari sharing on iDevice

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-safari, continuity

I've followed all the advice on other threads, none work. I have knocked the sliders in iCloud to off for Safari but I can still see what's being viewed on my iPad by double clicking my iPhone.

Comment: What advice? What threads?

Answer (score 4):

This feature is called Handoff.

> When your Mac computers and iOS devices are within Bluetooth range of
>   each other (about 33 feet or 10 meters), they can automatically “hand
>   off” what you’re doing from one device to another. For example, you
>   can start writing an email in Mail on your iPhone, then instantly pick
>   up where you left off in Mail on your Mac.

Follow the steps to turn it off:

1. Open the Settings app on your iOS device
2. Scroll down and tap ‘General’
3. Next tap ‘Handoff’
4. Turn the ‘Handoff’ toggle off

[image]